# how to get rid of escape character in a token with spirit::lex?

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-lex

I want to tokenize my own extension of SQL syntax. This involves recognizing an escaped double quote inside a double quoted string. E.g. in MySQL these two string tokens are equivalent: `""""` (the second double quote acts as an escape character) and `'"'`. I have tried different things but I am stuck at how to replace a token's value.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;

template <typename Lexer>
struct sql_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
  sql_tokens()
  {
    string_quote_double = "\\\"";    // '"'

    this->self("INITIAL")
      = string_quote_double [ lex::_state = "STRING_DOUBLE" ] // how to also ignore + ctx.more()?
      | ...
      ;

    this->self("STRING_DOUBLE") 
      = lex::token_def<>("[^\\\"]*") // action: ignore + ctx.more()
      | lex::token_def<>("\\\"\\\"") // how to set token value to '"' ?
      | lex::token_def<>("\\\"") [ lex::_state = "INITIAL" ]
      ;
  }

  lex::token_def<> string_quote_double, ...;
};
```

So how to set the token's value to `"` when `""` has been found?

Apart from that I have also the following question: I can write a functor for a semantic action to call ctx.more() and ignore the token at the same time (thus combining "low level" tokens into a "high level" string token). But how to elegantly combine this with lex::_state = ".." ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDITED** in response to comment, see below "UPDATE""

---

I suggest not trying to solve that in the lexer. Let the lexer yield raw strings:

```
template <typename Lexer>
    struct mylexer_t : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
    mylexer_t()
    {
        string_quote_double = "\\\"([^\"]|\\\"\\\")*\\\"";

        this->self("INITIAL")
            = string_quote_double
            | lex::token_def<>("[ \t\r\n]") [ lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore ]
            ;
    }

    lex::token_def<std::string> string_quote_double;
};
```

**NOTE** That exposing a token attribute like that, requires a modified token typedef:

```
typedef lex::lexertl::token<char const*, boost::mpl::vector<char, std::string> > token_type;
typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type> lexer_type;
```

Postprocess in the parser:

```
template <typename Iterator> struct mygrammar_t
    : public qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>()>
{
    typedef mygrammar_t<Iterator> This;

    template <typename TokenDef>
        mygrammar_t(TokenDef const& tok) : mygrammar_t::base_type(start)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        string_quote_double %= tok.string_quote_double [ undoublequote ];
        start = *string_quote_double;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(string_quote_double));
    }

  private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>()> start;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> string_quote_double;
};
```

As you can see, `undoubleqoute` can be any Phoenix actor that satisfies the criteria for a Spirit semantic action. A brain-dead example implementation would be:

```
static bool undoublequote(std::string& val)
{
    auto outidx = 0;
    for(auto in = val.begin(); in!=val.end(); ++in) {
        switch(*in) {
            case '"': 
                if (++in == val.end()) { // eat the escape
                    // end of input reached
                    val.resize(outidx); // resize to effective chars
                    return true;
                }
                // fall through
            default:
                val[outidx++] = *in; // append the character
        }
    }

    return false; // not ended with double quote as expected
}
```

But I suggest you write a "proper" de-escaper (as I'm pretty sure MySql will allow `\t`, `\r`, `\u001e` or even more archaic stuff as well).

I have some more complete samples in old answers here:

- TODO
- LINKS
- Here's a [search page with many related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20%5bboost-spirit%5d%20escape) using Spirit

---

## UPDATE

In fact, as you indicated, it is fairly easy to integrate the attribute value normalization into the lexer itself:

```
template <typename Lexer>
    struct mylexer_t : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
    struct undoublequote_lex_type {
        template <typename, typename, typename, typename> struct result { typedef void type; };

        template <typename It, typename IdType, typename pass_flag, typename Ctx>
            void operator()(It& f, It& l, pass_flag& pass, IdType& id, Ctx& ctx) const {
                std::string raw(f,l);
                if (undoublequote(raw))
                    ctx.set_value(raw);
                else
                    pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_fail;
            }
    } undoublequote_lex;

    mylexer_t()
    {
        string_quote_double = "\\\"([^\"]|\\\"\\\")*\\\"";

        const static undoublequote_lex_type undoublequote_lex;
        this->self("INITIAL")
            = string_quote_double [ undoublequote_lex ]
            | lex::token_def<>("[ \t\r\n]") [ lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore ]
            ;
    }

    lex::token_def<std::string> string_quote_double;
};
```

This reuses the same `undoublequote` function shown above, but wraps it in Deferred Callable Object (or "polymorphic functor") `undoublequote_lex_type` that satisfies [the criteria for a Lexer Semantic Action](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/abstracts/lexer_semantic_actions.html).

---

Here is a fully working proof of concept:

```
//#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_PRINT_SOME 80
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG // before including Spirit
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <fstream>
#ifdef MEMORY_MAPPED
#   include <boost/iostreams/device/mapped_file.hpp>
#endif
//#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_generate_static_lexertl.hpp>

namespace /*anon*/
{
    namespace phx=boost::phoenix;
    namespace qi =boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace lex=boost::spirit::lex;

    template <typename Lexer>
        struct mylexer_t : lex::lexer<Lexer>
    {
        mylexer_t()
        {
            string_quote_double = "\\\"([^\"]|\\\"\\\")*\\\"";

            this->self("INITIAL")
                = string_quote_double
                | lex::token_def<>("[ \t\r\n]") [ lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore ]
                ;
        }

        lex::token_def<std::string> string_quote_double;
    };

    static bool undoublequote(std::string& val)
    {
        auto outidx = 0;
        for(auto in = val.begin(); in!=val.end(); ++in) {
            switch(*in) {
                case '"': 
                    if (++in == val.end()) { // eat the escape
                        // end of input reached
                        val.resize(outidx); // resize to effective chars
                        return true;
                    }
                    // fall through
                default:
                    val[outidx++] = *in; // append the character
            }
        }

        return false; // not ended with double quote as expected
    }

    template <typename Iterator> struct mygrammar_t
        : public qi::grammar<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>()>
    {
        typedef mygrammar_t<Iterator> This;

        template <typename TokenDef>
            mygrammar_t(TokenDef const& tok) : mygrammar_t::base_type(start)
        {
            using namespace qi;

            string_quote_double %= tok.string_quote_double [ undoublequote ];
            start = *string_quote_double;

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(string_quote_double));
        }

      private:
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::vector<std::string>()> start;
        qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> string_quote_double;
    };
}

std::vector<std::string> do_test_parse(const std::string& v)
{
    char const *first = &v[0];
    char const *last = first+v.size();

    typedef lex::lexertl::token<char const*, boost::mpl::vector<char, std::string> > token_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<token_type> lexer_type;

    typedef mylexer_t<lexer_type>::iterator_type iterator_type;
    const static mylexer_t<lexer_type> mylexer;
    const static mygrammar_t<iterator_type> parser(mylexer);

    auto iter = mylexer.begin(first, last);
    auto end = mylexer.end();

    std::vector<std::string> data;
    bool r = qi::parse(iter, end, parser, data);

    r = r && (iter == end);

    if (!r)
        std::cerr << "parsing (" << iter->state() << ") failed at: '" << std::string(first, last) << "'\n";

    return data;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    for (auto&& s : do_test_parse( "\"bla\"\"blo\""))
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of how to match such a string with escapes with one regular expression - actually I regarded this impossible. Still I was aiming at/hoping for a simpler solution, i.e. not involving a grammar. Is this really needed? Maybe just for making testing/debugging easier?

Comment: @coproc Of course you can :/ It just wasn't what I'd suggest. I've added a wrapper `undouble_quote_lex` functor that shows you how to do this in pure lex (see **UPDATE**). The **[similarly adapted sample program](http://ideone.com/BGXH9W)** still prints `bla"blo` as expected

Comment: I am still chewing on the token type. What is the intention of the `char` type in the `mpl::vector` for the `AttributeTypes`? Wouldn't the type `std::string` suffice? Actually I do not understand why it is possible to have several attribute types in a token type definition and how they can be used.

Comment: @coproc Oh, you can drop the char, obviously. I had it there because I initially tried to work with your original token defs. Token value is a [variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/variant.html) over the types listed. It's all documented here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/lex/abstracts/lexer_primitives/lexer_token_values.html

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to solve this and similar tasks in the lexer, instead of make lexer return something intermediate and then parse it with extra code. Double quotes can be not the only complication inside strings, there can be other escapes and it is better to have clear description of the string parse process in one place and make lexer do ALL the job.

Here is the solution for the question in the topic using only lexer:

```
using namespace boost::spirit;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

template <typename Lexer>
struct sql_tokens : public lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
  sql_tokens()
  {
    string = '"';

    this->self +=
      lex::token_def<>('"')
      [
        lex::_state = "STRING",
        lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore,
        px::ref(curString) = std::string()
      ];

    std::string& (std::string::*append)(std::string::iterator,
                                        std::string::iterator)
    { &std::string::append<std::string::iterator> };

    this->self("STRING") =
      lex::token_def<>("[^\"]*")
      [
        lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore,
        px::bind(append, curString, lex::_start, lex::_end)
      ] |
      lex::token_def<>("\\\"\\\"")
      [
        lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore,
        px::ref(curString) += px::val("\"")
      ] |
      string
      [
        lex::_val = px::ref(curString),
        lex::_state = "INITIAL"
      ];

    this->self("WS") = lex::token_def<>("[ \\t\\n]+");
  }

  std::string curString;
  lex::token_def<std::string> string;
};
```