# Boost Spirit lexer states cross pollinate

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi, boost-spirit-lex

I am trying to use lexer states to do context specific parsing, but it seems that different lexer states do cross-pollinate. Here is a very basic example

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_operator.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_container.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace boost::spirit;

template <typename Lexer>
struct strip_comments_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer>
{
    strip_comments_tokens() 
      : strip_comments_tokens::base_type(lex::match_flags::match_default)
    {
        ccomment = "\\/\\*";
        endcomment = ".*\\*\\/";
        hello = "hello";

        this->self.add
            (ccomment)
            (hello);

        this->self("COMMENT").add
            (endcomment);
    }

    lex::token_def<> ccomment, endcomment;
    lex::token_def<std::string> hello;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct strip_comments_grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator>
{
    template <typename TokenDef>
    strip_comments_grammar(TokenDef const& tok)
      : strip_comments_grammar::base_type(start)
    {
        start =  *(   tok.ccomment 
                      >>  qi::in_state("COMMENT") 
                      [
                          tok.endcomment 
                      ]
              |   tok.hello [ std::cout << _1 ]
        );
    }

    qi::rule<Iterator> start;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    typedef std::string::iterator base_iterator_type;

    typedef 
        lex::lexertl::lexer<lex::lexertl::token<base_iterator_type> > 
    lexer_type;

    typedef strip_comments_tokens<lexer_type>::iterator_type iterator_type;

    strip_comments_tokens<lexer_type> strip_comments;           // Our lexer
    strip_comments_grammar<iterator_type> g (strip_comments);   // Our parser 

    std::string str("hello/*hello*/hello");
    base_iterator_type first = str.begin();

    bool r = lex::tokenize_and_parse(first, str.end(), strip_comments, g);

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the input

```
"hello/*hello*/hello"
```

to be tokenized as **hello ccomment endcomment hello**. But what happens is the input  gets tokenized as **hello ccomment hello**, so the grammar stops working. If you change the input to

```
"hello/*anything else*/hello"
```

everything works as expected.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cross pollinated from the [`[spirit-general]` mailing list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Boost-Spirit-lexer-states-cross-pollination-td4670410.html) :)

Answer (score 2):

You never modify the state of the lexer. So it's always in the `"INITIAL"` state.

Setting the lexer state should be done *in the Lexer stage* (there's no reliable way to feedback from the parser stage, in my experience and after much experimentation).

So you need to upgrade to `actor_lexer` and attach semantic actions to the token_defs added to the lexer tables:

```
typedef 
    lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<lex::lexertl::token<base_iterator_type> > 
lexer_type;
```

And

```
this->self += 
     ccomment [ lex::_state = "COMMENT" ]
   | hello;

this->self("COMMENT") += 
    endcomment [ lex::_state = "INITIAL" ];
```

That said, I suppose it's **much** easier to just skip the tokens altogether. If you really want to know how to use Lexer states for skipping see:

- [Boost.Spirit SQL grammar/lexer failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100628/boost-spirit-sql-grammar-lexer-failure/18106293#18106293)

I'd suggest the **Simplify And Profit** approach using `lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore` though:

- [Troubles with boost::spirit::lex & whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361519/troubles-with-boostspiritlex-whitespace/13367439#13367439)
- [how to get rid of escape character in a token with spirit::lex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516059/how-to-get-rid-of-escape-character-in-a-token-with-spiritlex/16526609#16526609)

Here's my take:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/18c67b13228db566)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/lex_lexertl.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp> // for the parser expression *strip_comments.hello

namespace lex = boost::spirit::lex;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

template <typename Lexer>
struct strip_comments_tokens : lex::lexer<Lexer> {
    strip_comments_tokens() 
      : strip_comments_tokens::base_type(lex::match_flags::match_default)
    {
        ccomment   = "\\/\\*.*\\*\\/";
        hello      = "hello"; // why not "."?

        this->self += 
             ccomment [ lex::_pass = lex::pass_flags::pass_ignore ]
  // IDEA: | lex::token_def<char>(".") // to just accept anything
           | hello
           ;
    }

    lex::token_def<lex::omit>   ccomment;
    lex::token_def<std::string> hello;
};

int main() {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator base_iterator_type;
    typedef lex::lexertl::actor_lexer<
                lex::lexertl::token<base_iterator_type/*, boost::mpl::vector<char, std::string>, boost::mpl::false_*/>
            > lexer_type;

    strip_comments_tokens<lexer_type> strip_comments;         // Our lexer

    std::string const str("hello/*hello*/hello");
    std::string stripped;

    base_iterator_type first = str.begin();
    bool r = lex::tokenize_and_parse(first, str.end(), strip_comments, *strip_comments.hello, stripped);

    if (r)
        std::cout << "\nStripped: '" << stripped << "'\n";
    else
        std::cout << "Failed: '" << std::string(first, str.end()) << "'\n";
}
```

Comment: My intention was to change the lexer state from the outside, because my parsing is context-specific and the lexer does not always know how to interpret the input stream. I believe this is the reason why qi::in_state exists. Currently I see no other way rather than to get rid of the lexer completely and put all the lex'ing stuff into the grammar, but it's too cumbersome a solution.

Comment: @AntonAutushka Mmm. I just updated my answer a bit with relevant links (see, in particular the comments on the first linked answer). Regarding "cumbersome" it has been my strong experience that using a lexer with Boost Spirit makes everything more cumbersome. My guidance would be: Be very sure you /need/ it and why.

Comment: Your code perfectly fixes the bug in my little ugly example. But this is not what I need. I need the in_state working :) To be more real life, consider these two guys "x = /b/g" and "x = a/b/g". The first one is a JavaScrsipt regexp, the second - an ordinary arithmetic expression. And you just can't tell one from another on the lexer level. Hence my situation.

Comment: That's just a wellknown scanner edgecase in that grammar (and similar languages). I'd make the lexer not care about it. You can have boatloads of performance benefits from just tokenizing (at the grammar level decide that it's a regex if an expression starts with `/`). If you haven't worked out that performance is an issue, I'd definitely consider not lexing.

Comment: If you want to parse the full ECMAScript language, I'd say **1.** don't roll your own **2.** don't feign "agility" using Spirit. Just use ANTLR, flex, CoCo/C++, ..., preferrably with an existing grammar definition.